# Alpha Vantage - Getting data for symbols containing space

Tags: alpha-vantage

I'm trying to get data (TIME_SERIES_DAILY) from the Nasdaq OMX exchange but fails on symbols containing a space. 
For example: 
`STO:ABB` works fine but `STO:ADDT B` does not. I've tried several combinations like `"STO:ADDT B"`, `STO:"ADDT B"`, `STO:ADDTB` or even `STO:ADDT_B` without luck.

Anyone solved this and knows how to correctly "encode" the symbol containing a space?

Answer (score 0):

try and use dash `-` for example `VOLV-B`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26452963)

Comment: @Dragonthoughts could you explain why you think this does not provide an answer to the question?  They asked how to encode a space, and were told to use a dash.  It looks like an answer to me.

Comment: As an answer, it is useful if it explains how and why it answer the question. This appears to be a comment on the lines of, "have you tried this..." It would be helpful if it referenced the part of the question's data that it attempts to provide a solution for, by for example, showing a corrected version of their content.